# Como fazer para que um input não aceite entrada em branco?

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<head>
    <title>WEB VIDEO AULAS</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->


</head>
<body>
<br/>   <br/>   <br/>   <br/>   <br/>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" size="35" id="palavra" placeholder="Digite seu nome ou sua matrícula.." required />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-blue" id="buscar" type="button">Buscar</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dados"></div>
    </div>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SLP/css/css/CDTpag1.css">
    <script>


        function buscar(palavra)
        {
            var page = "/SLP/css/css/busca.php";
            $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        url: page,
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $("#dados").html("Carregando...");
                        },
                        data: {palavra: palavra},
                        success: function (msg)
                        {
                            $("#dados").html(msg);
                        }
                    });
        }


        $('#buscar').click(function () {
            buscar($("#palavra").val())
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Em branco seria apenas espaços ou em branco seria nenhum valor inserido? Sua pergunta não tem nenhuma descrição que ajude a entender melhor o problema. Sugiro que faça uma edição.

Comment: possível duplicata https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193371/como-validar-campos-em-branco-em-html/193574#193574

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está capturando o evento `click` do elemento `#palavra`, o navegador acaba *"passando por cima"* da verificação do campo e executando a função `buscar()`.

Quando vc *"submete/"* o formulário, o próprio navegador checa os atributos `required` e `pattern` antes de prosseguir.

Sendo assim, altere a chamada da função `buscar()`:

```
        $('#buscar').click(function ()
        {
            if( $('#palavra').val() != '' && $('#palavra').val() != 'undefined' && $('#palavra').val() != null $('#palavra').val() != ' ' )
            {

                buscar($("#palavra").val())

            } else
            {
                alert("Você deve inserir seu nome ou matrícula!");
                return false;
            }
        });
```

No meu código fiz a verificação se o campo é vazio, mas vc pode colocar uma expressão regular por exemplo.

Coloquei um `alert` em caso de entrada inválida, que pode ser substituído por um código ao seu gosto, como mostrar uma div de erro abaixo do `input` por exemplo.

> Testado com *Google Chrome*!

Agora, *use a imaginação*!

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem, você não quer que o `input` não esteja vazio ou que ele contenha apenas espaço.

Eu faria algum simples assim:

```
$('#buscar').click(function () {

     var $palavra = $('#palavra');


     $palavra.val().trim().length && buscar($palavra.val());

      // ou

      if ($palavra.val().trim().length) {
          buscar($palavra.val());
      }
});
```

A sentença `$palavra.val().trim().length` avaliará se o valor de é `false` ou não através do número retornado. Se for zero, não será executado a função `buscar`. Isso porque o `trim` remove espaços em branco do início e do fim da `String`.

Outra opção sem `jQuery`, na minha opinião, seria definindo um `required` no `input` desejado e adicionando uma funcionalidade no `onchange` para remover espaços do início e do fim.

```html
<form>
<input type="text" required onchange="this.value = this.value.trim()">
<button type='submit'> Enviar </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione pattern ao seu input. Assim ele irá permitir apenas palavras. Caso usuário digite vários espaços ele não irá passar

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" size="35" id="palavra" placeholder="Digite seu nome ou sua matrícula.." required pattern="^[^-\s][a-zA-ZÀ-ú ]*">
```

Você pode validar também no javascript

```
$('#buscar').click(function () { 
      if( $("#palavra").val().length < 1 ) { 
          Alert("digite uma palavra")
          return false;
      } else {
          buscar( $("#palavra").val() );
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que voce possa usar somente jquery para fazer toda a verificacao necessaria para essa busca simples.
Eu faria uma modificacao somente nesta parte.

```
$('#buscar').click(function () {
  var keyword = $("#palavra").val();    // O valor pode ser algo como: '     oi     '
      keyword = $.trim( keyword );      // o trim vai remover os espacos do comeco e do fim: 'oi'
  if( keyword.length ){
    buscar( keyword );
  } else {
    alert( 'Busca em branco' );
  }
});
```